# Bootstrap - Scrollable table body CSS issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I've copied **exactly** this demo here: http://www.bootply.com/JnOYtO9xzn and I'm having issues with the CSS code. When I run it from my environment it looks like this:

[image]

However, when trying to reproduce what I'm seeing here in JSfiddle or anything else, it shows exactly how it's supposed to. Like this:

[image]

How can this be happening when the code is **exactly** the same?

**Edit:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>
        Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
      </h4>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-2">#</th><th class="col-xs-8">Name</th><th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">1</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td><td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">2</td><td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">3</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">4</td><td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td><td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">5</td><td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">6</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">7</td><td class="col-xs-8">Andy Parks</td><td class="col-xs-2">56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">8</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Skelly</td><td class="col-xs-2">96</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">9</td><td class="col-xs-8">William Defoe</td><td class="col-xs-2">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">10</td><td class="col-xs-8">Will Tripp</td><td class="col-xs-2">16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">11</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bill Champion</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">12</td><td class="col-xs-8">Lastly Jane</td><td class="col-xs-2">6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-fixed thead {
width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
height: 230px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
 display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
float: left;
border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Comment: Update question with your implementation code.

Comment: if possible provide a live link to your web page , so that we can check whats going on.

Comment: I'm running localhost. The pictures above should show everything. The code is Exactly the same

Comment: Is your bootstrap file complete or is it a custom download? You may have unchecked something you needed.

Comment: Also might be missing a normalize.css